# Как при нажатии на кнопку можно перейти по ссылке?

Tags: java, android

Как при нажатии на кнопку, открыть Google Play, и перейти на определенную страницу ссылку? Есть какие либо готовые решения и как это можно вообще реализовать?

Comment: Перед тем, как задавать вопрос, пользуйтесь поиском сначала в гугле, а потом по этому сайту. Не плодите одинаковые вопросы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно ссылку открыть так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

Точно также и ссылку на любое приложение

```
Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.mishaignatov.touristquiz&hl=en")
```

Приложение google play автоматом перехватит ссылку и откроет